# How to achieve sharing assets between multiple Angular.js apps hosted in different servers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frameworks, angularjs-directive

Hi I am  pretty new to Angular.js and trying to evaluate whether to use it for our next project.
Does anyone have any experience with building multiple Angular.js apps hosted in different servers (most likely Spring backend) that can share modules, templates and directives?

Basically, we have 3 apps, they perform similar functions but would have slightly different business logic based on roles...  Also for security, the apps may be hosted on different servers, one of which is behind a firewall.  I want to be able to share the as much as possible between the apps (asset, js, html, css, images, directives etc).  What are some best practices to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to share the same exact code?  In theory you could store it on a CDN of sorts (Basically your own server) and use a script tag to load in the JS.  Just reference images and other assets using absolute URLs.  Or are you talking about creating two independent apps that somehow communicate through JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

IMO one of the big advantages of AngularJS is that it lets you develop Web applications the way we used to develop enterprise software: well structured, well organized, strong patterns, etc.

But it's a mistake to think they're ever going to be 1:1. At the end of the day you're talking about a set of small script files. They aren't compiled (minification doesn't count), they don't have a **real** sense of identity or relationship with one another, etc. Any structure or re-use is going to come from you and how you develop your application.

Here are some starting points for some best practices:

- Learn and leverage directives and services. They're the heart and soul of Angular, and really what make it worth using in the first place. Basically, every singleton is a service (think "Managers") and every component or widget is a directive. When you start talking about re-use this is critical.

  You can make a widget called modalWindow and a manager called modalManager, and if you construct them carefully you can reuse these across all of the apps you described. Or, if you write them badly, you can make them hard to reuse! :) Spend some time here understanding this layer and you'll be happy you did.
- Learn and leverage Grunt (or Grasp or whatever, but Grunt is a great place to start if you're used to Ant). Your use case screams for build process, build automation, and maybe even Jenkins to tie all the pieces together.

  There's nothing in Angular that knows how to mix-and-match certain elements in the build process based on what the app needs (it has "dependencies" but only for JS - what if you have two versions of a widget and you want to make sure the correct one is loaded?) Grunt (or similar) will give you an enterprise-class build tool that will give you the rest of what you need behind the scenes.